# Posix message queue - multi writer & multi reader

Tags: posix, message-queue

I am confused about the queue (POSIX). 
Does multiple writer to queue or multiple reader from a queue needs to be protected?

multiple threads will write to the queue and multiple threads will read from the queue.

As the definition says "A message queue can have many readers and many writers ". But it is not saying if it needs protection or not.
should these two messages be protected by mutex?

mq_send(mqd_t mqdes, const char *msg_ptr, size_t msg_len, unsigned msg_prio);
mq_receive(mqd_t mqdes, char *msg_ptr, size_t msg_len, unsigned *msg_prio);

Please can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No you don't need to protect them with a mutex or such.  The kernel takes care of it.

See the ["ATTRIBUTES" section of the mq_send man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_send.3.html#ATTRIBUTES) online ("Thread Safety" is ["MT-Safe"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html)).

Comment: @Vincent - I had a citation once upon a time but can't find it right now.  If you look at man (7) pthreads it has a list of posix calls  which are exempt from being thread-safe and mq_send/mq_receive, both posix calls, are not among them.

Comment: @Vincent - From a practical perspective, if the MQs did not protect themselves they would be unusable.  Never mind threads, think in terms of processes.  If two distinct processes each had to protect a queue it would require they each share a mutex or semaphore and thus know of that entity in advance.  There has never been an example of msg queues shared between processes requiring such AFAIK.